# jQuery submit by form id conditions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have html form and want to make a validation by submitting the form with its specific id and validate it using jquery.
Here is my code:
**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" name="frmhot" id="contactform3412">
    <input type="text" name="status"/>         
    <input type="text" name="line"/>
    <input type="text" name="reason"/>
    <input type="text" name="partnum"/>
    <input type="text" name="badgescan"/>
    <input class="button_text" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "";
    jQuery("#contactform3412").submit(function(e){
        url= 'works well!';
    });
 alert(url);
</script>
</body>
```

For this example, i want to get the value of the javascript variable 'url' within the jQuery condition submit. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you mean your code does not work now?

Comment: You're updating your `url` on form submit but you're alerting that `url` outside that submit handler, fact is your `alert(url)` is invoked when your browser parses and executes that inline script where as the actual update to `url` won't happen unless you submit the form, so it will always alert url as empty

Comment: `get the value of the javascript variable 'url' within the jQuery condition`, can you pls elaborate on this part ? I'm not able to understand your intent :)

Comment: What i want to do here is after i submit the form, then it should give me the value of the variable 'url' which is 'works well!' and print it in alert. nothing seems to work out with that code

Comment: then you should put that alert statement inside that submit handler, which will update the url and alert you with the updated value on submitting the form

Comment: Not working even I put the alert inside the condition or below the url = 'works well!';

Comment: Here is my code that doesn't work.
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#contactform3412').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        url= 'works well!';
        alert(url);
    });
});

Comment: one more thing there's no document.ready() around your form handler, it's usually better to bind your event handlers in a `ready()`, so that the DOM is ready for your script to manipulate

Comment: pls add that code to your question rather than in the comments, it's more clear and likely to be noticed by every one who's trying to help :)

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery is properly loaded and that object is created ? Do you have exactly this `src="jquery-1.11.2.min"` in your html ?? you're missing the .js file extension :) It should be `src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psgy54cj/4/)

```
var url = "";
$("#contactform3412").submit(function(e){
    url= 'works well!';        
    alert(url);
    return  true;
});
```

Anyways you set url value and perform operations after submit,so use url  value there only. In your problem, url could not set to "works well" as submit event was not fired.

Comment: Thank you jQuery.PHP.Magento.com for your correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `js` file extension in your `script` declaration. It should be

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

With that, if you wrap your submit handler in document.ready(), it should work on click of form submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = '';
    $('#contactform3412').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        url= 'works well!';
        alert(url);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Arkantos, this really helps a lot. This answer my question.